# Joomla memcache session problem

Tags: joomla, memcached

Hi i have some troubles with memcached + joomla. I installed and started memcached => joomla options cache type memcache (write memcache options) and session type - memcache too. Save all options and after cann't login to site and administration. In error log nothing, when i change cache to database i can login, where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Joomla are you running and what is the browser / server combination?

I'm assuming you've cleared the browser cache after making these changes?

Some web servers, especially shared hosting, don't cycle as quickly as we'd like and I've experienced a lag in the time cache settings in Joomla are changed, and when they take effect...

Comment: Thanks Mark Matsusaaki but we did all the stuff as you suggested but when i put memory cache as session handler i am not able to login in the admin , so i think the best way to use memcache is just enable the memcache  and use session handler as database that's it

Comment: If you're running Joomla 1.5, have you cleaned the cache, under: 

Tools, Clean Cache, Site  ?

You can also Purge Expired Cache under Tools.

Answer (score 0):

this problem is very simple! go to your directory of joomla.

example:

```
/home/user/workspace/joomla
```

and open the file into the joomla folder:

"configuration.php"

with it opened change the line:

```
public $session_handler = 'memcache';
```

to

```
public $session_handler = 'database';
```

Alright? I hope that helped you.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use memcached for session cache. Use database or file cache for sessions.

Comment: Why is that? Is there any disadvantage of using memory as a cache for sessions?